# Breadth First Search on a Binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to traverse on a binary tree to find someone's ID by using his/her ID number. When I debug this function it works well, but on the other hand, when I directly run, it terminates itself.. Can someone figure it out please?

```
struct person{
char ID[15];
char name[30] ;
char surname[30];
person *left;
person *right;
};

struct tree{
person *root;
void bfsSearch();
void BFS(person*,char*);
};

void tree::BFS(person *root,char *search)
//BFS traversal on a binary tree
{
    char *temp;
    std::deque<person *> q;
    q.push_back(root);
temp=strncpy(temp,q.front()->ID,8);
while (q.size() != 0)
{
    person *next = q.front();

    if (strcmp(search,temp)==0)
    {
      cout<<"Result: "<<q.front()->ID<<endl;
      break;
    }
    q.pop_front();

    if (next->left)
        q.push_back(next->sol);
    if (next->right)
        q.push_back(next->sag);
    temp=strncpy(temp,q.front()->ID,8);
    }
}

void tree::bfsSearch()
{
    person *scan;
    char *data,*temp;
    data=new char[15];
    scan=root;
    cout<<"Enter the Person`s ID to search: ";cin>>data;
    BFS(root,data);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char *temp;
temp=strncpy(temp,q.front()->ID,8);
```

You are copying data into an uninitialized pointer, which is undefined behavior. You need to declare `temp` as an array, or allocate it dynamically. Since you are only copying up to 8 bytes, using `char temp[9];` should be enough. Note though that `strncpy` will leave the string unterminated if the input was too long, so you'd need to add `temp[8]=0;` to be safe.

There is also no point in assigning the result of `strncpy` back to `temp`, since it just returns its first argument.

It's much better to do things the C++ way: Use `std::string` and avoid all this messing around with `char` pointers and null-terminators.

Comment: I did it, still same. but the weird is that when I search for the ID number which is located at the right side of root, it works perfect. it occurs error when i try to search left side of root